# How to use modulo in tables?

Tags: php

How to use modulo in PHP tables?

```
<table border="1">
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++): ?>
    <?php if ($i % 5 == 0): ?>
        <tr>
    <?php endif ?>  
        <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
    <?php if ($i % 5 == 0): ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endif ?>  
<?php endfor ?>
</table>
```

This example show me:

```
1   2   3   4
5
6   7   8   9
10
11  12  13  14
15
16  17  18  19
20
```

I would like receive:

```
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
```

What I must use in if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's look at what you are doing: you *start* a row when $i is a multiple of five and you *end* a row when $i is a multiple of five. in any other case, you just print the number.
so your row can only contain the value 5.

but: you want a row containing 1,2,3,4,5 - so you have to finish the row after 5, what you are doing, but *start* it before 1.

```
<table border="1">
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++): ?>
    <?php if ($i % 5 == 1): ?>
        <tr>
    <?php endif ?>  
        <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
    <?php if ($i % 5 == 0): ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endif ?>  
<?php endfor ?>
</table>
```